# SQL Server Combination query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a third party application that needs an alternate name list for street names. The developers provided a Python script that will generate the list, but the time it takes to generate is horrible. What I am trying to do is create a query or stored procedure that will create all the different combinations for street names and maintain the JOINID for each name.
This is what the source looks like.

```
JOINID   StreetName
147      PAULSON RD
165      NORTH AVE
270      E SCHOOL RD
212      OAKWOOD AVE
```

The results would look like this:

```
JOINID  StreetName
147     PAULSON
147     PAULSON RD
165     NORTH
165     NORTH AVE
270     SCHOOL
270     E SCHOOL
270     SCHOOL RD
270     E RD
270     E SCHOOL RD
212     OAKWOOD
212     OAKWOOD AVE
```

The results would exclude values such as a single RD or other road type.

This is the current query that I am working with. This returns the split list with the corresponding ID's

```
'SELECT        
   JOINID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Streetname
   FROM  
   SELECT JOINID, CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([StreetName], ' ', '</M><M>') + </M>'
   AS XML) AS CVS FROM  [L].[ROADCENTERLINESHF]) AS A CROSS APPLY 
   CVS.nodes('/M')   AS Split(a)`
```

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Getting all possible permutations is not going to be fast, especially if there is a lot of data. You need to define some business rules about which permutations you want to exclude. I noticed you included NORTH from 165 but excluded E from 270. I suspect you will have a pretty good list of exclusions (court, ct, road, rd, rr, po, p.o., ave, avenue, st, street, etc...)

Comment: I have this which gives me the split list with the corresponding ID's. 'SELECT        JOINID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Streetname
FROM            (SELECT        JOINID, CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([StreetName], ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS
                          FROM            [L].[ROADCENTERLINESHF]) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)' @Shachaf.Gortler

Comment: @SeanLange The exclusion list so far isn't too bad, currently 31. The reason that you see the difference between E and North would be based on the structure of the street name. The E is a pre-directional so they use an abbreviation. While the North is the base street name. The software and department that this supports utilizes abbreviations for the  pre and post types that make up the street name.

Comment: Can you explain some of the logic here? For "E School RD" why do you not have "School E RD"? And why not E? Or is E one of the exceptions? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @SeanLange The list is being created to support a third party application that uses a geocoder. The developer wants to do is essentially make it as simple as possible for the user to get to a specific street. That is why they create the different combinations of the street names. They are excluding the directional values like E, W, S, and N. Along with the types of streets like RD, DR. It helps minimize the number of returns when a user does a search. There is no School E RD due to the methodology they use for the Python script. From a rules perspective School E RD would be a valid return.

Comment: OK. So what have you tried? It seems you want to keep the values in order?

Comment: @SeanLange 'SELECT        JOINID, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Streetname
FROM            (SELECT        JOINID, CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([StreetName], ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS
                          FROM            [L].[ROADCENTERLINESHF]) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)' This will split the names with they corresponding ID's.

Comment: @user29402 You need to edit your question and include that query in your question, rather than posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a function that splits each string up into a table/list of values and ordinals.  Then from those results, insert all of the values into a temp table and begin your query from that table.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[Split](
 @String nvarchar (max),
 @Delimiter nvarchar (200)
 )
returns @ValueTable table (
    [id] int IDENTITY(0,1),
    [Value] nvarchar(max)
)
begin
 declare @NextString nvarchar(max)
 declare @Pos int
 declare @NextPos int
 declare @CommaCheck nvarchar(1)

 --Initialize
 set @NextString = ''
 set @CommaCheck = right(@String,1) 

 --Check for trailing Comma, if not exists, INSERT
 --if (@CommaCheck <> @Delimiter )
 set @String = @String + @Delimiter

 --Get position of first Comma
 set @Pos = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
 set @NextPos = 1

 --Loop while there is still a comma in the String of levels
 while (@pos <>  0)  
 begin
  set @NextString = substring(@String,1,@Pos - 1)

  insert into @ValueTable ([Value]) Values (@NextString)

  set @String = substring(@String,@pos +1,len(@String))

  set @NextPos = @Pos
  set @pos  = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
 end

 return
end
```

Here is a version of the moden split function as mentioned in the comments that also includes an ordinal.
`

```
--select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden('The quick brown fox jumped over the  lazy dog.', ' ', 0)
--select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden('The quick brown fox jumped over the  lazy dog.', ' ', 1)
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Moden
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255),
   @RemoveEmptyEntries BIT = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N1) ordinal
    FROM cteStart s
    WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)) <> ''
            OR
            @RemoveEmptyEntries = 0
          );
```

`

Comment: Please don't use loops to split strings. It is unbelievably inefficient. Here are several other splitters that will perform far better than this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: UGH. I use the Moden splitter regularly but Aaron had to modify it for his article and the performance is horrible when the delimited list is nvarchar(max). The original article from Jeff Moden can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/